# Is TCP maximum segment size (MSS) "clamping" compatible with IPv6?

Tags: tcp, ipv6, layer4, transport-protocol, icmpv6

With IPv4, TCP MSS "clamping" (a network device editing the MSS value in a TCP header) can help when path maximum transmission unit discovery is not working. (e.g., when ICMP is being blocked somewhere in the path.) Since there's no fragmentation in IPv6, we still have ICMPv6's 'packet too big' to signal the originating end point.

Is there any guidance about clamping TCP MSS over IPv6 specifically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well technically fragmentation can happen in IPv6; [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fragmentation) is the wikipedia article on it.

[This](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/erx/junose93/swconfig-ip-ipv6-igp/ipv6-tcp-configuration.html) Juniper page is a bit old but it shows that you can clamp an MSS for TCP over IPv6 on Junos the same as you would in IPv4 using the same command, `tcp mss`. The same is shown in [this](http://blog.ioshints.info/2013/01/mtu-issues-and-tcp-mss-clamping-in.html) article for Cisco IOS 15, using the traditional ip tcp `adjust-mss` command.

So you can configure MSS clamping if PMTUD isn't working as it should be in a part of your network, otherwise, you should be ensuring that you are aiding the smoothing running of PTMUD across your networking so that MSS clamping isn't required (I understand this isn't always under your control).

**Update**

[Here](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junose10.0/information-products/topic-collections/swconfig-ip-ipv6/setting-mss-for-tcp-connections_1.html) is a link to a newer Junos article for Junos 10x rather than 9, I can't find one for 11 and I'm not in front of 11 right now, but I expect it will be the same.

Comment: ...am I reading the fragmentation description correctly? IPv4 fragmenting could happen at any hop in the route, while in IPv6, the routers must drop the packet (notify via ICMPv6) and then fragmentation is done by the end-points?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Fragmentation in v6 is not done by the routers unless the router is acting as a host. IE: Management traffic over v6, etc.

Comment: There's a subtlety here in that at least the IOS version of adjust-mss is broken, in that it clamps v6, but incorrectly: http://blog.ioshints.info/2013/01/mtu-issues-and-tcp-mss-clamping-in.html

Answer (score 3):

There are definitely cases - usually involving IPv6-in-IPv4 tunnels at some point along the path - where even if PMTUD works correctly, MSS negotiation fails. In this case a TCP session may start correctly (since the SYN/ACK packets are small) but no data packets arrive (since those packets are too big for the tunnel). In this case MSS clamping at the far end would help, but is not under control of the "victim" waiting for the packets. The fail-safe solution is for both ends to set the IPv6 MTU to 1280, which should get through any tunnel.

Comment: "_MSS negotiation fails._" MSS is _not_ negotiated. Each side sends, in the SYN, what its MSS is. The other side needs to respect the MSS sent by the other side, and each can be different. MSS is not negotiated, it is dictated. One, or both, side(s) could set MSS to '0', meaning that there is no MSS in that direction, and any size segment can be sent in that direction. That is explained in RFC 793.